# Changing values of a Class variable

Tags: javascript

I'll apologise in advance, if this is something straightforward. I'm at a bit of a loss as to what technical terms I need to actually search for the documentation on this. It's fairly straight forward stuff. I have a class, an instance of that class and a function I want to run, that would change one of the values established in the class constructor. Below you'll find an example that's effectively, exactly what I'm aiming for.

```
class CLASS {
  constructor(name) {
    this._name = name;
    this._round = 0;
    this._wins = 0;
    this._losses = 0;
  }

  get name(){
    return this._name;
  } 

  ...

}

const PL1 = new CLASS('Player 1');

...

function updatePL(player, pointsFor, pointsAgainst) {
  if (pointsFor > pointsAgainst) {
    return player.wins++ } else if ...
  ...

}



console.log(PL1); // Prebiously "console.log(player)" Edited. Not source of issue in actual code.  

updatePL(PL1, 1, 0);

console.log(PL1); //No changes
```

I've tried various means of adding and subtracting, both inside and outside the function. I'm stumped. Moreover, I was performing fairly similar similar steps inside something like this with no issues:

```
object = [{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  },
  {
    ...
  }];
```

Again, the technical terms elude me so I don't known what to look for. Any information, even if it's just pointing me in the vague direction of a google search term, would be fabulous. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the full code, without the `...`s, so we have a [MCVE]?

Comment: Looks like your class has not defined a `set wins()` setter. So how are you expecting modifying `classInstance.wins` to affect `classInstance._wins`?

Comment: `console.log(PL1);` not `console.log(player);`

Comment: Given your current code, `player` exists only inside `updatePL`.

Comment: @connexo ... Ah. Of course it was something like that. You are a star. Thank you!

Comment: player is passed by reference so it shouldnt just exist only inside the function, right

Comment: Do not add in stuff like _"Its been solved"_ into your question, use the built-in methods to accept a given answer or create a self answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to `console.log(PL1)` instead of `console.log(player)`, cuz player is local to your `updatePL` function. Also you used `_wins` in the class but `wins` in `updatePL` so make sure you're using the same.

In between though, why declare PL1 as constant when you're mutating it ?
Also you don't need to return `player.wins` from `updatePL`, you can alway access this prop from the object itself like so `PL1.wins.` or `PL1.your_getter`

Comment: PL1 is declared as a constant because it should always refer to the object defined by the class. In the event I mishap and accidentally type something like "PL1 = 1" it will throw an error, when ran. Thus far, I haven't came across any problems acting on values inside the object. I could be wrong though, or overlooking something. I'm quite far behind anything resembling competency. As you can probably infer by my inability to add the correct variable names to something as simple as a console.log when typing up an example snippet. Ha. If I'm miles off the bar, in my thinking. Let me know. :)

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. I don't think you'll run into any issues acting on the props of `const`, so you're not wrong. I personally prefer using it on only objects I don't intend to mutate but they are useful in other defensive cases like yours. :) you're not off the bar, we all make mistakes along this journey and it's a never ending one (there will always be something new to learn).